# What is the point in using "<prefix:TagName>" in a custom xhtml tag for a public API

Tags: api, language-agnostic, xhtml

Facebook API provides the capability to use "XFBML".
it's a set of tags that have an FB: prefix. here is an example:

```
<fb:like href="http://MyWebSite.com" 
         width="10" 
         layout="standard" 
         action="like" 
         show_faces="true" 
         share="true">
 </fb:like>
```

I would like to create a public API for my website that will allow to incorporate a button on other websites (clicking the button will move the user to a certain action on my website)

what is the advantage of using such a convention of `<prefix:TagName>`?
and then parsing it with a custom JS code that will change the element to a button.

I could also just use `<MyCUstomTagName data-param1="" data-param2="">` and so on...

Am I missing some important difference between the two methods ?

Answer (score 1):

The only advantage is it's probably marginally easier to read. But using colons in element names causes problems if authors ever want to use them with real XHTML (i.e. pages served as `application/xhtml+xml`), so you'd do better to avoid them.

Better would be to use a hyphen instead. You could then define then in accordance within the strictures of [Custom Elements](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/).